# DI, resolve service implementations from the factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an interface and multiple implementations of it:

```cs
interface IFoo { bool CanFoo(); }
class Foo1 : IFoo { bool CanFoo() => true; }
class Foo2 : IFoo { bool CanFoo() => false; }
```

I would like to register all of them in the `IServiceCollection` and provide a custom implementation factory like this:

```cs
services
    .AddTransient<IFoo, Foo1>()
    .AddTransient<IFoo, Foo2>();

// register the factory last
services.AddTransient<IFoo>(provider =>
{
    var registrations = provider.GetServices<IFoo>(); // Exception

    return registrations.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CanFoo());
};
```

So as you might see the idea is to resolve the first available implementation. This code however results in `StackOverflowException` because `provider.GetServices<IFoo>()` tries to resolve the factory as well, even though it doesn't implement the interface, leading to an endless loop.

So a couple of questions:

1. Is it expected for the service provider try to resolve the factory in this case?
2. How can I overcome this, if possible?

**Update**

The reason why the factory was involved in the first place is because the correct service must be selected at **runtime** based on the input data, which may change with every new request. Therefore I cannot narrow this down to a specific service registration during the application startup.

Comment: [GetServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getservices?view=aspnetcore-2.2) *creates* services, it doesn't return their registrations. When you call it,  it will try to create services by instantiating any registered types *and* factories. If you call it inside the factory you get a recursive call

Comment: This code is rather weird though. Are you going to create N temporary objects each time you want a single `IFoo` but only keep one of them? It looks like you're trying to implement filtering in DI. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct, that's the idea. I realize it isn't perfect but I need to delegate the ability to process the request to the service. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can get the registrations through `services` instead of `provider`. You could check each [ServiceDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicedescriptor?view=aspnetcore-2.2)'s ServiceType for `IFoo` and use reflection on the ImplementationTypes to find which of them have specific attributes or implement additional "marker" interfaces. Register the concrete classes, `Foo1`, `Foo2` instead of their interface and use the factory to pick the one you want from the service descriptors

Comment: What are the actual criteria you want to use? Why call a method on the concrete class?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks. I thought about it but it seems too heavy and overkill for my case. I think I may need to redesign this or just use switch case on the implementations like the answers below suggest.

Comment: Why does it seem overkill? That's what you tried to do in the first place only you tried to *create* the service instances as well. What you tried is actually a lot more expensive. Besides, how are you going to write the `switch`? Based on what criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your code fails because for the dependency injection container, your factory *is* a valid source for an instance of `IFoo`. So when asking to resolve all services of `IFoo`, the factory will be asked for it just as well.

If you want this to work, then you will have to separate the types in some way. For example, you could create a marker interface `IActualFoo` which you use to register your services instead:

```
services.AddTransient<IActualFoo, Foo1>()
services.AddTransient<IActualFoo, Foo2>();
```

Inside of your `IFoo` factory you could then resolve the `IActualFoo` and cast them down to `IFoo`. Of course this means that `IActualFoo` would inherit from `IFoo` and that your `Foo` services actually have to implement `IActualFoo`.

---

A different approach would be to move the responsibility to select the correct `IFoo` implementation into the factory. As noted by others, your approach has the downside that it will create instances for every single implementation of `IFoo` and only then select the right instance. That’s very wasteful.

It would be better if the factory could make the decision to select the right `IFoo` implementation. Usually, this would look like this:

```
services.AddTransient<Foo1>();
services.AddTransient<Foo2>();
services.AddTransient<IFoo>(sp =>
{
    if (someMagicCondition)
        return sp.GetService<Foo1>();
    else
        return sp.GetService<Foo2>();
});
```

So the factory would create the right instance depending on some condition logic. While this approach is often used, it requires full responsibility within the factory and a limited set of possible `IFoo` implementation at design time. So this will not work if you want to dynamically add implementations later.

What you could also do is register a set of `IFoo` *factories*. So instead of having the `IFoo` implementation decide whether it is the right implementation, move that logic to a factory for each `IFoo` implementation:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFooFactory, Foo1Factory>();
services.AddSingleton<IFooFactory, Foo2Factory>();
services.AddSingleton<IFoo>(sp =>
{
    var factories = sp.GetServices<IFooFactory>();
    return factories.FirstOrDefault(f => f.CanFoo())?.CreateFoo();
});
```

```
public interface IFooFactory
{
    bool CanFoo();
    IFoo CreateFoo();
}

public Foo1Factory : IFooFactory
{
    public bool CanFoo() => true;
    public IFoo CreateFoo() => new Foo1();
}
public Foo2Factory : IFooFactory
{
    public bool CanFoo() => false;
    public IFoo CreateFoo() => new Foo2();
}
```

Of course, instead of newing up the `Foo` implementations within the factory, you can also pass the service provider and resolve them (if they are registered).

Comment: I like the idea with a set of factories but it would still be expensive. Now that I was pointed out to it I'm starting to think more about the performance.

Comment: No, it wouldn’t be that expensive since the factories wouldn’t be recreated at all times. They are registered as singletons.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the *actual* problem is how to pick a service implementation based on some criteria. The exception is thrown because `GetServices` returns all *services* produced by the registrations, including the factory method itself. When the factory calls `GetServices` it ends up calling itself recursively until there's a StackOverflowException.

Another problem is that `GetServices()` will actually *create* the service instances but only use one. The other one is discarded. This results in garbage objects and can be expensive if the service itself is expensive or controls a resource like a database connection.

The recursion can be avoided if services are registered directly and the factory method calls `GetService` with the desired type once it decides which one it wants ::

```
services
    .AddTransient<Foo1>()
    .AddTransient<Foo2>();

// register the factory last
services.AddTransient<IFoo>(provider =>
{
    var type=PickFooType();

    return provider.GetService(type);
};
```

The trick now is picking the correct type. That depends on the actual critera. It's one thing to pick a type based eg on some configuration or easily accessible state, it's quite another picking it based on the implementation class's properties.

In the "easy" case, let's assume one needs to pick the correct type based on a flag or configuration setting. Picking the type could be a simple `switch`.

If that setting is available at startup one can avoid the factory and simply register the desired type.

There are cases where the setting can change during runtime though. For example, should one remote service provider fail we may need to fail over to another one. In the simplest case, one could use a simple switch :

```
Type PickPaymentProvider()
{
    var activeProvider=LoadActiveProvider();
    switch (activeProvider)
    {
        case 'Paypal':
            return typeof(Foo1);
        case 'Visa' :
            return typeof(Foo2);
        ...
    }
}
```

**Update - Context-based dependency resolution**

From the question's update it seems that the problem isn't how to create a factory. It's how to pick a service based on the context of each individual request (parameter values, environment variables, data, whatever). That's called context-based dependency resolution. It's available in advanced DI containers like [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) but not .NET Core's DI implementation and abstractions.

The proper way to add it would require adding middleware that replaces the DI resolution step before each request. The quick&dirty way is to add the factory function itself as a service and call it when required. That's what Rahul shows in his answer.

This means that `AddTransient` will have to register a *Function* that accepts the parameters needed for resolution :

```
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    IFoo resolver(MyParam1 param1,MyParam2 param2)
    {
        var type=PickFooType(param1,param2);    
        return provider.GetService(type);
    }

    return resolver;
};
```

This registers a `Func<MyParam1,MyParam2,IFoo>`. The controller can ask for this function either through constructor or [action injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#action-injection-with-fromservices) :

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices] resolver,int id,MyParam1 param1...)
{
    MyParam2 param2=LoadFromDatabase(id);
    IFoo service=resolver(param1,param2);
    var result=service.DoSomeJob();
    return OK(result);
}
```

By registering the *factory* instead of the `IFoo` interface, we can register services by interface again.

```
services
    .AddTransient<IFoo,Foo1>()
    .AddTransient<IFoo,Foo2>();
```

If we need to call every registered service and ask it if it can service our request, we can use `GetServices` again :

```
services.AddTransient(provider =>
{
    IFoo resolver(MyParam1 param1,MyParam2 param2)
    {
        var firstMatch=provider.GetServices<IFoo>()
                               .First(svc=>svc.CanFoo(param1,param2));
        return firstMatch;
    }

    return resolver;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question since I realized that certain criteria was missing and it confused people.

Comment: @Zabavsky that's a different problem again. You are asking for context-based dependency resolution which *isn't* available in .NET Core's DI infrastructure. It's available in other DI containers like AutoFac. Properly adding it would require chaning how the request middleware chain works, which is *not* hard. Registering a *function* like you seem to try and do, is the "quick & dirty" way.

Comment: Even though I love Autofac my project is quite small to involve such a big guns. I'll go with @poke's approach with multiple factories. Thanks for your answer, it's highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a factory like

```
        serviceCollection.AddTransient(factory =>
       {
           Func<string, IFoo> mytype = key =>
           {
               switch (key)
               {
                   case "Foo1":
                       return factory.GetService<Foo1>();
                   case "Foo2":
                       return factory.GetService<Foo2>();
                   default:
                       return null;
               }
           };
           return mytype;
       })
```

From wherever you are trying to use the type you can declare and inject it

```
private Func<string, IFoo> newType;
```

You can call then

```
newType("Foo1").CanFoo();
```

Comment: What's `key` and how do I use the registration?

Comment: @Zabavsky *you* have to decide what that key is (and post it in the question). As for registrations, those are available only through `services`, not `provider`

Comment: @Zabavsky based on your update, *this* looks like the best answer

Answer (score 0):

the below code first registers `Foo1` for `IFoo` then replaces service for `IFoo` with `Foo2`.

```
services
  .AddTransient<IFoo, Foo1>()
  .AddTransient<IFoo, Foo2>();
```

for your third query,

You cannot do it because you are trying to generate registration for `IFoo` using `IFoo` which causes `StackOverflowException` which is expected (as you have already mentioned).

What you have do is. First register each service seperately,

```
 services
  .AddTransient<Foo1>()
  .AddTransient<Foo2>();
```

then use conditional registration using factory Method.

```
serviceCollection.AddTransient(factory =>
{
    //get the key here. you can use factory.GetService
    // to get another service and extract Key from it.
     switch(key)
     {
         case "Foo1":
              return factory.GetService<Foo1>();
              break;
         case "Foo2":
              return factory.GetService<Foo2>();
              break;
         default:
              return null;
      }
}
```